# How to Return Text with IF Function in an Array

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to query a column and look for a state abbreviation, and if that abbreviation is a match, then "`East`" if not then "`West`"

Wanting to return text values in my column based on state abbreviation. We have territory manager split into two domains--East and West. So, trying to easily sort my data by East/West.

Here's what I have:

```
=IF(M:M={"AL", "CA", "DE","FL","GA","IA","KY","ME","MD","MA","MN","MS","NH","NJ","NY","ND","RI","SD","TN","VT","VA","WV","WI"},"East","West")
```

But, when I fill down, it just fills down East, and does not seem to actually query M:M

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the cleanest code, but this should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A), IF((A:A = "foo")+(A:A = "bar") = 1, "WEST", "EAST"), ))
```

To use `IF` with an `OR` in an `ARRAYFORMULA`, you evaluate the column with 1s and 0s. The `A:A = "foo"` will evaluate to 1 if `foo` is in the cell. So if one of your `OR` criteria is in the cell, the total value in the `IF` will be `1`.

You have a lot of criteria so writing each of them in will take a while ...

E.g. `IF( (A:A = "AL") + (A:A = "CA") ... (A:A = "WI") = 1, "East", "West")`

Comment: Great. Thanks for this! Much appreciated. Awesome.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I just copied (M:M="AL)+ and pasted in edited each state abbreviation. Thanks again so much!

Comment: No worries, and glad to help. Please close the question, by checking the question as answered. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I marked this as answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISERROR/MATCH():

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(M:M,{"AL", "CA", "DE","FL","GA","IA","KY","ME","MD","MA","MN","MS","NH","NJ","NY","ND","RI","SD","TN","VT","VA","WV","WI"},0)),"West","East")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your solution on this. Much appreciated!